# How to configure vim to interact with interactive command line shells?

Tags: vim, terminal-multiplexer, remote-control

From time to time I want to use vim as scratch pad for commands that I would like to send to a command line shell like `psql` (Postgres), `ghci` (Haskell programming language), `octave` ('calculator'), `gnuplot` (plot) etc.

The advantages would be that you could put comments next to command lines, directly document your session, incrementally develop command lines, test examples ad-hoc in manuals etc.

Pro features I would like to use: send a selection to a shell, send e.g. the next 10 lines to a shell, display the output of a shell command into a vim output buffer, into a vim yank-register, directly insert it etc.

There should be some support of a shell-session concept, i.e. the shell should not be started for each command from scratch.

I could live with a kind of remote controlled xterm which I would put side by side to a vim window.

Comment: A bonus tip: bash supports vi-keybindings with `set -o vi` which enables more advanced editing of the command line.

Comment: @htor, yup, this is also useful, but it is really a different use case (btw. setting `set editing-mode vi` in `~/.inputrc` gives you that experience in all readline enabled applications).

Comment: And btw, Ctrl-X Ctrl-E in Bash opens your `$EDITOR` with the current command, so you can edit it as you like. The command will be run when you quit the editor.

Comment: @AxelKnauf Ctrl-X Ctrl-E ... it is `ESC` `v` ! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime), an environment inspired by Emacs's SLIME mode. It sends the contents of Vim to a screen or tmux session.

In the future you can probably also use [Xiki](https://github.com/trogdoro/xiki), but for now its Vim support is incomplete.

Comment: vim-slime is great - `C-c-c` sends the current *paragraph* to the specified screen-window (screen is used by default). I'd like to configure a key-binding for just sending the current line - probably not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

maxschlepzig: This is an old thread but I hope it may be still useful to provide info that I just learnt about vim-slime. 
You can configure the following keybinding (F2 in this case) in .vimrc to send current line.

`vmap <F2> :SlimeSend<CR>`

`nmap <F2> :SlimeSend<CR>`

F2 can be replaced by any other key.

Comment: you should add a link to the manual or tutorial for vim-slime for those who don't know what it is. Also include a snippet of why this is useful or a short example. Both will make this answer much more popular.